# Is there any way to stop the ASP.NET Development Server from being created for all projects?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a solution with multiple projects in it. When I want to debug the project I'm working on, an ASP.NET Development Server is created for all the projects in my solution. My projects are not inter-dependent, so I don't need the others to run. Is there any way to tell VS not to create dev servers for the other projects?

(I realize I could split the projects into their own separate solutions, but for now the multiple projects under one solution is what it is and won't be changing for now.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click on the projects name in Solution Explorer, in the properties pane you have the option to set 'Always Start When Debugging' under 'Developer Web Server' to false.

Comment: Ahh, so simple! I was pouring through the Properties page (not the Properties pane) looking for the setting with no luck. Didn't even think about looking at the property pane (I have it closed by default). Thanks!